# How to sort the timestamp with the closest value?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, timestamp, difference

I have 2 dataframes:

1. **Sensor readings**

```
#Making a dataset with sensor readings
index = pd.date_range(start='1/12/2020', end='4/12/2020', freq='0.5H')

columns = ['Sensor ' + str(n) for n in range(1,5)]

data = np.random.uniform(1,25,size=(4369, 4))

df_sensor_readings = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns).head()
```

2. **Temperature predictions**

```
#Making a dataset with temperature predictions
index = pd.date_range(start='1/12/2020', end='6/12/2020', freq='0.7H')

columns = ['Sensor ' + str(n) for n in range(1,5)]

data = np.random.uniform(1,25,size=(5212, 4))

df_temp_predictions = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

#Taking 10% null values in the dataset
for col in df_temp_predictions.columns:
    df_temp_predictions.loc[df_temp_predictions.sample(frac=0.1).index, col] = pd.np.nan

df_temp_predictions.head()
```

The goal is to match the sensor readings with the closest temperature prediction. By closest I mean with the closest timestamp. There can be 100s of sensors but initially I have taken only 4.

The output should be a dataframe with following columns-

1. The sensor timestamp (index)
2. The closest temperature to the timestamp
3. The prediction value
4. Type of sensor (ex- Sensor1 or Sensor2 etc)

So far I have reached-

```
def nearest(ts,s):
    # Given a presorted list of timestamps:  s = sorted(index)
    i = bisect.bisect_left(s, ts)
    return min(s[max(0, i-1): i+2], key=lambda t: abs(ts - t))

val_sensor_readings = df_sensor_readings.index.values
predictions_ts= df_temp_predictions.index.values

for temp_ts in val_sensor_readings:
    closest_timestamp = nearest(temp_ts,predictions_ts)
```

Comment: Create a diff column then sort by that?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but it seems to me like you're essentially there: Set `idx =[nearest(temp_ts, predictions_ts) for temp_ts in val_sensor_readings]` and then select the corresponding predictions `df = df_temp_predictions.loc[idx]` to further work with them. Am I missing something?